# ipv6 problems in linux - slow to not connection problems

Tags: ipv6

I have experienced slow to not connections due to ipv6.
However, I like to understand why the problem persists in linux for ipv6.

It is hung on ipv6

```
 ping -4 google.com
PING  (142.250.187.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sof02s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.187.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from sof02s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.187.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from sof02s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.187.110): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=33.4 ms
64 bytes from sof02s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.187.110): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from sof02s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.187.110): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=22.2 ms
^C
---  ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.923/24.508/33.404/4.454 ms
(base) elias@eliasc:~$ ping -6 google.com
PING google.com(sof02s44-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4017:80d::200e)) 56 data bytes

(forever hung)
```

and here:

```
 ip -6 addr list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a02:85f:f09f:b868:1d08:5c1e:5523:a55f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 577994sec preferred_lft 59400sec
    inet6 2a02:85f:f09f:b868:68ca:478f:135b:6471/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2565048sec preferred_lft 577848sec
    inet6 2a02:85f:f02e:2f85:7e6:adb5:7359:d44e/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 577994sec preferred_lft 59400sec
    inet6 2a02:85f:f02e:2f85:8e42:6d7d:b971:dc85/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591965sec preferred_lft 604765sec
    inet6 2a02:85f:f09f:b868:4414:4d8c:717:dd12/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 576307sec preferred_lft 57713sec
    inet6 fe80::e7ad:7295:e675:4ecc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
(base) elias@eliasc:~$ ip -6 neigh show
fe80::1 dev enp3s0 lladdr 74:9d:79:65:28:38 router REACHABLE 
(base) elias@eliasc:~$  ip -6 route list
2a02:85f:f02e:2f85::/64 dev enp3s0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
2a02:85f:f09f:b868::/64 dev enp3s0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vmnet1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vmnet8 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp3s0 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev enp3s0 proto ra metric 20100 pref high
```

and here:

```
traceroute6 google.com
traceroute to google.com (2a00:1450:4017:80d::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  *^C
(base) elias@eliasc:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.187.110), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  vodafone.station (192.168.2.1)  0.306 ms  0.364 ms  0.411 ms
 2  loopback2004.med01.dsl.hol.gr (62.38.0.170)  13.958 ms  13.974 ms  13.935 ms
 3  * * *
 4  ae3-100-ucr1.atm.cw.net (195.89.103.89)  15.000 ms  15.126 ms  16.210 ms
 5  ae24-xcr1.sof.cw.net (195.2.16.5)  32.984 ms  32.357 ms  32.937 ms
 6  72.14.218.54 (72.14.218.54)  29.679 ms 72.14.208.246 (72.14.208.246)  27.225 ms 209.85.149.140 (209.85.149.140)  27.844 ms
 7  * * *
 8  209.85.243.244 (209.85.243.244)  28.219 ms^C
```

cat /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost (USER)
127.0.1.1   USER

127.0.1.2       test.com
127.0.1.3       www.test.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

```
 cat /etc/host.conf 
multi on
```

Nothing uncommented (run) on sysctl.conf

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp3s0  -l ip6
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
17:13:08.145234 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:13:08.458055 IP6 eliasc.55242 > _gateway.5355: Flags [S], seq 4257863812, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 4114399771 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
17:13:08.458369 IP6 _gateway.5355 > eliasc.55242: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 4257863813, win 0, length 0
17:13:10.092653 IP6 _gateway > eliasc: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has eliasc, length 32
17:13:10.092682 IP6 eliasc > _gateway: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is eliasc, length 24
17:13:13.265418 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
17:13:13.274832 IP6 eliasc > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 8 group record(s), length 168
17:13:13.344671 IP6 eliasc.38984 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.http: Flags [S], seq 3695938649, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168040687 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:13:13.492016 IP6 eliasc.36950 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.5355: Flags [S], seq 372145597, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168040835 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
17:13:13.492030 IP6 eliasc.36952 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.5355: Flags [S], seq 4007085850, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168040835 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
17:13:13.558853 IP6 eliasc > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 8 group record(s), length 168
17:13:13.707454 IP6 eliasc.36956 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.5355: Flags [S], seq 2244580855, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168041050 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
17:13:14.518857 IP6 eliasc.36952 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.5355: Flags [S], seq 4007085850, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168041861 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:13:14.518874 IP6 eliasc.36950 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.5355: Flags [S], seq 372145597, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168041861 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:13:15.365689 IP6 eliasc.39002 > 2606:4700:e6::ac40:cb02.http: Flags [S], seq 3071295745, win 64440, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 168042708 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:13:16.175326 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:13:18.486829 IP6 eliasc > _gateway: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has _gateway, length 32
17:13:18.487081 IP6 _gateway > eliasc: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 24
17:13:24.205373 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:13:32.235457 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:13:38.972915 IP6 _gateway > eliasc: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has eliasc, length 32
17:13:38.972944 IP6 eliasc > _gateway: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is eliasc, length 24
17:13:40.265529 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:13:48.295627 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:13:56.325678 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:14:04.355729 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:14:07.853186 IP6 _gateway > eliasc: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has eliasc, length 32
17:14:07.853219 IP6 eliasc > _gateway: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is eliasc, length 24
17:14:10.135972 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
17:14:10.146865 IP6 eliasc > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 8 group record(s), length 168
17:14:10.806855 IP6 eliasc > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 8 group record(s), length 168
17:14:12.385798 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
17:14:13.014825 IP6 eliasc > _gateway: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has _gateway, length 32
17:14:13.015120 IP6 _gateway > eliasc: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 24
17:14:20.415846 IP6 _gateway > ip6-allnodes: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is _gateway, length 32
```

here with strace (flooding with such messages:

```
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=128}, 0)        = -1 EAGAIN (the resource is temporarily unavailable)
sendto(3, "\200\0\0\0h\243\0$?\301}e\0\0\0\0\345$\16\0\0\0\0\0\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27"..., 64, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(58), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2a00:1450:4017:80d::200e", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 64
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=128}, 0)        = -1 EAGAIN (the resource is temporarily unavailable)
```

according to this post i changed my network interfaces [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616856/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ipv6-address-to-etc-network-interfaces) and restarted network services, but yet no connection through ipv6,

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
network 10.0.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255

iface enp3s0 inet6 static
  address 2001:db8:1:2::2
  netmask 64
  # Add additional IPv6 addresses when $IFACE goes up
  up ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:1:2::3/64 dev $IFACE
  up ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:1:2::4/64 dev $IFACE
  # Remove them when $IFACE goes down
  down ip -6 addr del 2001:db8:1:2::3/64 dev $IFACE
  down ip -6 addr del 2001:db8:1:2::4/64 dev $IFACE
```

```
ip -brief -6 address
enp3s0           UP             2a02:85f:f09f:b868:1d08:5c1e:5523:a55f/64 2a02:85f:f09f:b868:68ca:478f:135b:6471/64 2a02:85f:f02e:2f85:7e6:adb5:7359:d44e/64 2a02:85f:f02e:2f85:8e42:6d7d:b971:dc85/64 2a02:85f:f09f:b868:4414:4d8c:717:dd12/64 fe80::e7ad:7295:e675:4ecc/64
```

UPDATE

- This address 2001:db8:1:2::2 was found somewhere. Dont know if this is valid for my pc.

Weird things:

- By restarting network services with additional lines of inet6 uncommented in interface, lost entirely internet connection.
- By commenting all additional inet6 lines in interface, without rebooting and restarting all internet services, still no internet.
- By commenting all additional inet6 lines in interface, with rebooting, still no internet. BUT by restarting all internet services,
  internet came back!
- Weird fact? Now ipv6 is working! What the h*ll?
- I can hypothesize that some config files / variables were changed internally in kernel or elsewhere silently by making these changes?
  Dont know.
- Because i tried many times to restart services, i think the line that played the most role is that, i dont know why:
  `pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp3s0/accept_dad` which was changed back to 1 when internet worked again (only after rebboting, restarting services, not before).
- My conclusion ipv6 support in linux still is very problematic. User must make a lot of debugging, trial-and-error in order to work. Some sites support it, some sites dont support it. Some sites get slow when connecting through ipv6, others are faster. So, it is somewhat a messup yet.
- I dont know yet if when i reboot i will have internet or ipv6 will work.

```
 # Restart network services
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart;
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop;
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start;
sudo systemctl restart networking;
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager;
sudo systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed.service;
sudo systemctl restart fwupd.service ifplugd.service ifupdown-pre.service ifupdown-wait-online.service iio-sensor-proxy.service irqbalance.service ModemManager.service networkd-dispatcher.service networking.service NetworkManager-dispatcher.service NetworkManager.service network-online.target nftables.service sshd.service ssh.service ssh.socket systemd-networkd.service systemd-networkd.socket systemd-network-generator.service;
```